# Unable to install SGX driver to intel i3 6100 CentOS 7 machine

Tags: sgx

I am trying to install the Intel SGX driver at Intel I3 6100 based CPU and I am not able to launch the enclave.

I am suspecting that it is happening due to my processor (i.e. Intel core i3). Same steps I perform at my another machine that came with I7 and it is working as expected.

Thing I tried at my end is :

First I tried to install the driver 1.7 and getting the device error.

========================================================

```
[root@local_host POC1]# ./sgx_linux_x64_driver_51b2884.bin

Unpacking Intel SGX Driver ... done.

Verifying the integrity of the install package ... done.

Installing Intel SGX Driver ...

/tmp/sgx-driver-d9jY01 ~/POC1

install -d /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package

install -d /opt/intel/sgxdriver/scripts

install package/* /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package

install scripts/* /opt/intel/sgxdriver/scripts

~/POC1

/opt/intel/sgxdriver/package ~/POC1

make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/opt/intel/sgxdriver/package modules

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64'

  CC [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx_main.o

  CC [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx_page_cache.o

  CC [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx_ioctl.o

  CC [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx_vma.o

  CC [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx_util.o

  LD [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx.o

  Building modules, stage 2.

  MODPOST 1 modules

  CC      /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx.mod.o

  LD [M]  /opt/intel/sgxdriver/package/isgx.ko

make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64'

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'isgx': No such device
```

===========================================================

Second I tried to install the SGX 2.1.0 driver and driver install successfully but I am unable to launch enclave.

============================================================

```
./app

Info: Please make sure SGX module is enabled in the BIOS, and install SGX driver afterwards.

Error: Invalid SGX device.

Enter a character before exit ...
```

============================================================

Note : I verified at BIOS and SGX is enabled there.

Comment: In case any one can suggest me what else i can looked upon, kindly share.

Comment: in my case it start working after reboot. So after installing the driver and PSW you need to restart the machine so services and driver can be load successfully.